# Multiple PHP array split

Tags: php, arrays

```
array (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12);
array (b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12);
array (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12);
```

From upper array I want to do this:

```
array (a1, a2, a3, a4);
array (b1, b2, b3, b4);
array (c1, c2, c3, c4);

array (a5, a6, a7, a8);
array (b5, b6, b7, b8);
array (c5, c6, c7, c8);

array (a9, a10, a11, a12);
array (b9, b10, b11, b12);
array (c9, c10, c11, c12);


//etc.
```

I will also have opportunities columns check. 4-columns above or 3.

The list is really long.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php. This took me five seconds to Google "php break array into smaller arrays". Try for yourself before asking others.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: but that is not the same. see my requirements again. maybe you should first read my question properly.

Comment: The others didn't mean that `array_chunk()` will give you **exactly** what you want. But you can use it to split the arrays into chunks which you can then assemble into a multidimensional array, if that's what you want as it's not exactly clear.

Comment: @rafig maybe you should first phrase your question properly. "I will also have opportunities columns check. 4-columns above or 3."? What does that even mean?

Comment: Sorry. You are right. The array_chunk is right. With Columns I meant the integer specified in array_chunk. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$input_array = array ("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9", "a10", "a11", "a12");
var_dump(array_chunk($input_array, 4, true));
```

Out put :

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'a1' (length=2)
      1 => string 'a2' (length=2)
      2 => string 'a3' (length=2)
      3 => string 'a4' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'a5' (length=2)
      1 => string 'a6' (length=2)
      2 => string 'a7' (length=2)
      3 => string 'a8' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'a9' (length=2)
      1 => string 'a10' (length=3)
      2 => string 'a11' (length=3)
      3 => string 'a12' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
$a = array (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12);
$b = array (b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12);
$c = array (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12);

$a_chunk = array_chunk($a,4);
$b_chunk = array_chunk($b,4);
$c_chunk = array_chunk($c,4);
```

We can test the output by printing the chunks:

```
print_r($a_chunk[0]);
print_r($a_chunk[1]);
print_r($a_chunk[2]);
```

Resultant output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a1
    [1] => a2
    [2] => a3
    [3] => a4
)
Array
(
    [0] => a5
    [1] => a6
    [2] => a7
    [3] => a8
)
Array
(
    [0] => a9
    [1] => a10
    [2] => a11
    [3] => a12
)
```